# Xamarin Navigation Issue

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm have an issue that I can not understand, I want to navigate from MainPage to another page (CheckPage), Then I want to back to the MainPage, Programmatly it's work but there is a white space from the top when I back to the MainPage, See the screenshot

[image]

MainPage Code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="xamrinApp.MainPage">

<StackLayout>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="DimGray" HeightRequest="100">
        <Label Text="Xamarin App" FontSize="22" Margin="0,50,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"/>
    </Grid>

    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin application" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10"/>
    <Label Text="Please select from the list:" FontSize="16" Padding="30,0,30,0"/>

    
    <Entry x:Name="enRegistrationNumber" Margin="10"></Entry>
   <Button x:Name="btnClickMe" Text="Fetch" Clicked="btnClickMe_Clicked" />

    <Label x:Name="laResult" Text="..." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>

    <Button x:Name="btnCheckRecord" Text="Check Record" Clicked="btnCheckRecord_Clicked"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Check record button code

```
App.Current.MainPage  = new NavigationPage(new CheckRecordPage());
```

**CheckRecord page code**

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="xamrinApp.Views.CheckRecordPage">

<Grid BackgroundColor="LightYellow">
    <Button x:Name="btnBack" Text="Back" Clicked="btnBack_Clicked"></Button>
</Grid>
```

**Back button code**

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how navigation works.  Please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

when you first assign the `MainPage` in `App.xaml.cs`, wrap it in a `NavigationPage`

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyFirstPage());
```

then when you want to navigation from the first page to the second page

```
// in MyFirstPage
this.Navigation.PushAsync(new MySecondPage());
```

when you want to navigate back to the first page, your user can either use the back button, or you can do this programatically

```
// in MySecondPage
this.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: When I trying to use PushAsync I got this error “PushAsync is not supported”

Comment: which platform are you testing on?  Is that the **exact** error message you get?

Comment: "platform" means iOS/Android.  And you did not answer the other question I asked you.

Comment: The error appears in iOS, Yes that is the exact message for the error

Comment: did you wrap your first page in a NavigationPage as shown in the first example?

Comment: In app.xalm.cs? I just assigned the MainPage

Comment: I can share the application if you, It’s a test app

Comment: So you completely ignored the first step of my suggestion?

Comment: It works, But I have a question .. in this case the MainPage work as container that hold all the pages, it does not appears at all ?! Or I still not understanding :(

Comment: Read the docs I linked to.  NavigationPage is a container that allows you to navigate between pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the AppShell try to navigate with :

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"YourPageName");
```

Don't forget to register a route for your page in AppShell.xaml.cs in the constructor :

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(YourPageName) , typeof(YourPageName));
```